# AngularJS File Structure

Tags: angularjs

I know there are other threads related on how scripts could be organized within the `root` folder and interact with views (using `ng-route`).

I was planning to have this kind of file structure to keep my scripts structurized within a single `ng-app` value. *Yet, this can be reconsidered if necessary.*

```
root
|- app
   |- controller   // where all controllers per view are placed
   |- factory           
   |- directive    
   |- config 
   |- // other angular features
   app.js          // routing implementation
|- css
   |- lib
   |- view
|- js
   |- lib
   |- view  
|- view
   |- view1.html
   .
   |- viewN.html
index.html
```

So basically the contents of `index.html` would be like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- GLOBAL STYLESHEET LINKS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/*.css" />
</head>
<body ng-app="appName">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <zb-route-styles></zb-route-styles>
    <!-- Library Import -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/*.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And `/root/app/app.js` would have this content:

```
var app = angular.module("appName", ["ngRoute", "routeStyles"]);
app.config(routeConfig);
app.factory("FactoryName", factoryName);
app.controller("ViewNCtrl", viewNCtrl);
```

My questions are:

- Did I get the file structure right?
- What are the flaws using this structure?
- Since I am using [Angular Route Styles](https://github.com/tennisgent/angular-route-styles), is there similar implementation for controllers so that there's no need for me to include controllers scripts on `index.html` just on the route configuration?

So basically instead of this:

**/root/index.html** `<body>`

```
<script src="app/controller/*.js"></script>
```

Is there any angular library for this syntax

**/root/app/config/routeConfig.js**

```
.when("/view1", {
    templateUrl: "view/view1.html",
    controller: "View1Ctrl",
    css: "css/view/view1.css,
    js: "app/controller/view1.js"
})
```

If you have clarifications, just make a comment for me to address it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to structure an AngularJS application.  The 2 main ways are organizing by type & organizing by feature.

By TYPE:

```
root/
|-app/
  |-controllers/
  |-services/
  |-views
```

By FEATURE:

```
root/
|-app/
  |-checkout/
  |-dashboard/
  |-users/
```

While the example you present is by type, I suggest to structure by feature.  It is better organized to handle your app as it scales.  Also, it is easier to sort through the code base as new members join the team.